# How to navigate to another page with the click of a button that's already inside a page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

- I have a *Window* that contains a **frame**.
- I have two pages, **Page1** and **Page2**, and ... inside them, I
  have a **Button**.
- When the *Window* is loaded the **frame** navigates to Page1.

I want the frame to navigate to **Page2** by clicking on the **Button** in the **Page1**.

---

I tried to use MVVM:

That's the Window XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Course.Navigation">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:NavigationViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="frame" Content="{Binding Page, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Window ViewModel:

```
public class NavigationViewModel
{
    private static object page;
    public static object Page { get { return page; } set { page = value; } }

    public static void ChangePage(object objpage){Page = objpage;}

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        ChangePage(new Page1());
    }
}
```

The Page1 XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="MVVM_Course.Page1">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:Page1ViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnGoTo2" FontSize="50" Command="{Binding BtnPage2Command}" Content="Go to Page 2"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The Page1 ViewModel:

```
class Page1ViewModel
{
    private ICommand btnPage2Command;
    public ICommand BtnPage2Command { get { return btnPage2Command; } set { btnPage2Command = value; } }
    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        BtnPage2Command = new RelayCommand(GoToPage2);
    }
    private void GoToPage2(object obj)
    {
        NavigationViewModel.ChangePage(new Page2());
    }
}
```

> When I compile, the frame navigates to Page1 but clicking on the
>   Button does not change the Page. Using the debugging red circle tool
>   it seems to be working, the property "Page" in NavigationViewModel
>   changes from Page1 to Page2 but... the result is that nothing actually
>   happens in the UI.

Comment: See this: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: @adPartage Thanks, In the link you sent, I discovered that it is possible to navigate without reference to the frame by using the NavigationService and It worked.

Comment: The only problem now is that I cannot access the navigation service from the ViewModel class.

Comment: One way to solve this is by passing the Navigation Service  to the ViewModel constructor (from the view&#39;s code-behind - where you will now be initializing and setting the DataContext).